# SapMaxDB Connectivity

Tags: database, jdbc, maxdb

I found a docker container for SapMaxDB database:

```
docker run --name=sapmaxdb -p 7200:7200 -p 7210:7210 -d maxshahrokni/maxdb
```

Which are the username, password and database to connect to this container?

I found the driver class `com.sap.dbtech.jdbc.DriverSapDB` and `url="jdbc:sapdb://{HOST}[:{PORT}]/{DB}"`